# Increase values of object in array by using function

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I started to work with prototyping but I have a lot of missing knowledge.

Currently I got a case. Im creating new Object with array as value for employees, every employee got age property. I'd like to extend Array map inside of my function so I can iterate and change value by specific function, called increaseAge.

```js
function increaseAge(amount) {
  this.age += amount;
}
function Administration(employees) {
  this.employees = employees;
  
  Array.prototype.increaseAge = function(amount) {}
}

const newAdministration = new Administration([{ age: 1}, { age: 1}]);
newAdministration.employees.increaseAge(1);

console.log(newAdministration)
```

How can I increase result for every employee by specific value by calling increaseAge? 
Where is best source of knowledge to master this subject of JavaScript?

Comment: `employees ` will be an array. So you have to access with index or a loop. (`newAdministration.employees[0].increaseAge(1);`)

Comment: Don't do `Array.prototype.increaseAge = function(amount) {}`. There is a better to solve your problem (and it wouldn't make sense to put this assignment in the constructor anyway). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate on the problem. (e.g. do you want to increase the age of all employees or just one of them? If the latter, how do you want to choose which one? etc)

Comment: @sandrooco: No, `increaseAge` does not exist on the objects inside the array.

Comment: @FelixKling +1. Don't modify javascript default object.

Comment: Is there any way to use without accesing index (for ex.map foreach)?

Comment: @wudoem: There are multiple ways to iterate over an array if that is what you are asking about. If you want to add `1` to every age, you can just do `employees.forEach(e => e.age += 1)`.

Comment: Maybe you can use underscore.js. See the `_.where()` function. https://underscorejs.org/#where

Comment: You guys want to iterate and actualy hardcode, I'd like to use function increaseAge() which actually should be interpreted as an abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`increaseAge` should not be a method on `Array.prototype` (that would add it to all arrays), but on `Administration.prototype`. Then you can use `employees.forEach` as mentioned in my comment:

```js
function Administration(employees) {
  this.employees = employees;
}

Administration.prototype.increaseAge = function(amount) {
  this.employees.forEach(function(employee) {
    employee.age += amount;
  });
};

const newAdministration = new Administration([{ age: 1}, { age: 1}]);
newAdministration.increaseAge(1);

console.log(newAdministration)
```

A more modern version of this would be to use class syntax, which hides the whole prototype business.

```js
class Administration {
  constructor(employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
  }

  increaseAge(amount) {
    this.employees.forEach(employee => employee.age += amount);
  }
}

const newAdministration = new Administration([{ age: 1}, { age: 1}]);
newAdministration.increaseAge(1);

console.log(newAdministration)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be iterated, indeed, but change of values should happen by function ageIncrease() which is positioned at top.

Comment: Of course it is an answer. I just provide an approach. It's up to you to adopt it to your specific situation. You can organize your code however you want. You can do `this.employees.forEach(function(employee) { increaseAge.call(employee,  amount); });`.